# Resolve import for the :Move Motor for BBC micro:bit

Tags: python, import, bbc-microbit

How can I resolve the import statement for the :Move Motor for BBC micro:bit? According to this [github repository](https://github.com/KitronikLtd/micropython-microbit-kitronik-MOVE-motor) it should be possible to write a python script for the Move Motor. But if I try to compile the script it says no module named KitronikMOVEMotor.

The code for the move motor is on this [repository](https://github.com/KitronikLtd/pxt-kitronik-move-motor). It has also a lot of python snippets.

But if I try to install this via pip it says that this is no python project. How can I resolve the import for KitronikMOVEMotor? I have searched in the python index for packages from Kitronik, but with no results.

I should be possible to import this somehow or this repositories should never compile.

Comment: I don't think the micro:bit has pip. I think you have to follow the instructions at https://python-editor-2-2-3.microbit.org/help.html?snippets=true#fs

Comment: I didn't know this web-based IDE existed. In this editor it compiled.